# Delete expired tokens in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have set up an OAuth2 client-credentials flow with a [Spring Security Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) (org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.0) and a standard setup taken from [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server) that I extended by a database layer. I have one resource server, one client application with multiple clients and the authorization server. Everything works perfectly except for the point that expired tokens keep stacking up in my database.

I defined a `RegisteredClientRepository`-bean using the `JdbcRegisteredClientRepository` for my clients and a `OAuth2AuthorizationService`-bean using the `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` for the authorizations. My tokens expire after five minutes and the client requests a new token. The `OAuth2Authorization` entities containing the token remain in the database and I don't find a way to get them cleaned up.

So the `OAuth2AuthorizationService` can remove authorizations with `remove(OAuth2Authorization authorization)` and also has a `findById(String id)` method that gives you the authorization but these are generated UUIDs that I don't know. So I have no way of obtaining the authorization that I want to delete. There is no `findAll()` method or anything in this direction.

What am I overlooking here? Does Spring have a cleanup job? Is this somehow configurable or something else that I don't know of?

Best regards

EDIT:

I helped myself out by writing custom sql that is scheduled with a cron once a day. This is a lean solution but has the disadvantage that I now depend on the database (postgres uses `NOW()` but other databases may not) and the table structure from spring. I extended the `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` to have the code close to where the other database operations are done and the original table name is found. This class is exposed as a `OAuth2AuthorizationService`-bean.

kotlin:

```
class ExpiredTokenDeletingOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations: JdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository: RegisteredClientRepository)
  : JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository) {

  val REMOVE_AUTHORIZATION_SQL = "delete from oauth2_authorization where access_token_expires_at < NOW();"

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
  fun removeExpiredAuthorizations() {
    jdbcOperations.update(REMOVE_AUTHORIZATION_SQL)
  }
}
```

But I still suppose there is a better way...

Comment: I use jdbcTemplate to query
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030222/how-to-get-pageregisteredclient-in-spring-authorization-server)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my point is to avoid accessing the database directly per SQL at all :)

Comment: I am surprised as well that the default Spring implementation does not deal with that, and nothing is mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html). Even worse: Spring Boot configures by default an `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService`, which will cause memory leaks (my current issue, even though we have a custom implementation). [spring-boot #24237](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24237) also mentions this issue. I assume the goal of storing those tokens in database is to use them in background calls?