# How to get Page<RegisteredClient> in Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to add or update RegisteredClient use my custom controller,so first need to show the RegisteredClient's list.

so I want to get Page use `RegisteredClientRepository.findAll(Pageable pageable)`,but RegisteredClientRepositor have no findAll method ,just have `findById`,`findByClientId`

How can I get The RegisteredClient's list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I use `jdbcTemplate` to query

```java
@Component
public class CustomRegisteredClientRepo {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


  public Page<CustomClient> findAll(Pageable page) {
    Order order = !page.getSort().isEmpty() ? page.getSort().toList().get(0) : Order.by("id");

    SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM oauth2_registered_client ORDER BY "
        + order.getProperty() + " " + order.getDirection().name() + " LIMIT " + page.getPageSize()
        + " OFFSET " + page.getOffset());

    long count =
        jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from oauth2_registered_client", long.class);

    List<CustomClient> list = new ArrayList<CustomClient>();

    while (rs.next()) {
      CustomClient client = new CustomClient();
      client.setId(rs.getString("id"));
      client.setClientId(rs.getString("client_id"));
      list.add(client);
    }
    return new PageImpl<CustomClient>(list, page, count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).